# Cannot update Google Drive file with new file version using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Script that will look at emails with a specific label, pull an excel attachment from the email and then update an existing excel file in Google Drive with the extracted attachment. I think I have successfully started pulling the attachment but I cant seem to update the existing Google Drive excel file with the newly extracted attachment. I'm also hoping to run this script on the newest email marked with my label. Here's what I have so far but Google Script keeps inserting random text inside the excel file instead of my expected content (for example, it recently added `function () { [native code] }` to the excel file).

Here's what I have so far:

```
function UploadToDrive() {
  var labelName = "Port"; // The label you set up in Gmail
  var targetFolderName = "Schedules"; // The name of the target folder in Google Drive
  var targetFileName = "Schedule.xlsx"; // The name of the target file in the target folder

  // Get all threads with the specified label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    // Get the most recent thread
    var mostRecentThread = threads[0];

    // Get the latest message in the most recent thread
    var messages = mostRecentThread.getMessages();
    var latestMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];

    // Check for attachments in the latest message
    var attachments = latestMessage.getAttachments();

    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      var attachment = attachments[k];
      var attachmentName = attachment.getName().toLowerCase();

      // Check if the attachment filename contains the specific phrase
      if (attachmentName.includes("Work Schedule".toLowerCase())) {
          var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(targetFolderName).next();
          var targetFile = targetFolder.getFilesByName(targetFileName);

          if (targetFile.hasNext()){
            var file = targetFile.next();
            file.setContent(attachment.setDataFromString)
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few different types of data in the setContent method with no luck. The results are always the same.

Comment: setDataFromString is a method and should be written as setDataFromString().  However, I don't think writing to an Excel file like that is going to work.  What makes you think that it should?

Comment: Are you trying to put the contents of an email attachment into a cell.  Perhaps you should convert the excel file to a Google Spreadsheet first.

Comment: This question has been solved in another thread that I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77897594/what-is-the-proper-way-of-updating-a-file-through-the-manage-version-function/78017965#78017965

Answer (score 0):

Methods are written this way:

try changeing:

```
 attachment.getBytes
```

to:

```
attachment.getBytes()
```

or to:

```
attachment.getDataAsString()
```

but I don't think writing to an Excel file like you are attempting is going to work.  It might be easier to start with a google spreadsheet and put the data into the spreadsheet and then convert it to xlsx format.  There are numerous examples of that on SO.

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. It looks like it might be overloading the file as I get an error when refreshing the file that reads `The file is too large to open. Please try with a smaller file.` if I try and call getBytes(). I get a different error message if I try and call getDataAsString(): `File could not open. Try refreshing the page.`

Comment: I think you entire approach is flawed.  You cannot load data into an Excel file.  I recommend statinng with a Google Spreadsheet and then convert to XLSX.  You can overwrite a google spreadsheet with an XLSX.  Tanaike has as example of that.

Comment: I'm not so much trying to load data into an excel file as much as I am trying to update the version of an existing excel file on google drive. Google drive offers an option to "manage versions" of a given file whereby you maintain the same link to a file but can upload newer versions of said file. That way, any shared links remain the same but you can indefinitely upload newer versions.

Comment: Perhaps but file.setContent is designed to replace the entire contets of the file so that's not going to work with an xlsx file.  I think you need to ask a different question.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. I will ask a new question with your suggestions in mind.