# What is the proper way of updating a file through the "manage version" function on Google Drive using Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been able to successfully pull email data and update file contents on a Google drive file using the `setContent()` method in Google Scripts. What I am really looking for, though, is to take the entire file that is attached to the email and update the version of an existing file on Google drive. This way the shareable link that I have created to this Google drive file remains valid and the file itself gets updated to the newest version.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
function UploadToDrive() {
  var labelName = "Port"; // The label you set up in Gmail
  var targetFolderName = "Schedules"; // The name of the target folder in Google Drive
  var targetFileName = "Schedule.xlsx"; // The name of the target file in the target folder

  // Get all threads with the specified label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    // Get the most recent thread
    var mostRecentThread = threads[0];

    // Get the latest message in the most recent thread
    var messages = mostRecentThread.getMessages();
    var latestMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];

    // Check for attachments in the latest message
    var attachments = latestMessage.getAttachments();

    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      var attachment = attachments[k];
      var attachmentName = attachment.getName().toLowerCase();

      // Check if the attachment filename contains the specific phrase
      if (attachmentName.includes("Work Schedule".toLowerCase())) {
          var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(targetFolderName).next();
          var targetFile = targetFolder.getFilesByName(targetFileName);

          if (targetFile.hasNext()){
            var file = targetFile.next();
            file.setContent(attachment.setDataFromString())
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding in a method like this that leverages the Drive API but I cant get it to work as I get an error stating `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property update on object Apiary.drive.files.`

```
// Function to update the version of the target file in the given folder
function updateTargetFileVersion(attachment, targetFolder, targetFileName) {
  var targetFiles = targetFolder.getFilesByName(targetFileName);

  if (targetFiles.hasNext()) {
    // If the file with the same name exists, update its version
    var targetFile = targetFiles.next();

     // Get the new content as a Blob
    var newContentBlob = Utilities.newBlob(attachment.getContentType(), attachment.getDataAsString());

    // Create a new revision by uploading the new content
    var updatedFile = Drive.Files.update({}, targetFile.getId(), newContentBlob);

    // Set the name to ensure it's the correct version
    updatedFile.setName(targetFileName);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please note `file.setContent(attachment.setDataFromString())` the methold setDataFromString() has two parameters and you supplied none. [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment#setdatafromstringstring)

Comment: What is the managed version function ... do you have a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get this working. I was indeed missing a parameter as Cooper suggested. I also reworked a few other things in the code. Here's what's been working for me so far without any issues:

```
function UploadToDrive() {
  var labelName = "Port"; // The label you set up in Gmail
  var targetFolderName = "Schedules"; // The name of the target folder in Google Drive
  var targetFileName = "Schedule.xlsx"; // The name of the target file in the target folder

  // Get all threads with the specified label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var threads = label.getThreads();


  if (threads.length > 0) {
    // Get the most recent thread
    var mostRecentThread = threads[0];

    // Get the latest message in the most recent thread
    var messages = mostRecentThread.getMessages();
    var latestMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];

    // Check for attachments in the latest message
    var attachments = latestMessage.getAttachments();

    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      var attachment = attachments[k];
      var attachmentName = attachment.getName().toLowerCase();

      // Check if the attachment filename contains the specific phrase
      if (attachmentName.includes("Work Schedule".toLowerCase())) {
          var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(targetFolderName).next();
          var targetFile = targetFolder.getFilesByName(targetFileName);


        // Update the content of the target file with the new version
        updateTargetFileVersion(attachment, targetFolder, targetFileName);
      }
    }
  }


}

function updateTargetFileVersion(attachment, targetFolder, targetFileName) {
  var targetFiles = targetFolder.getFilesByName(targetFileName);

  if (targetFiles.hasNext()) {
    // If the file with the same name exists, update its version
    var targetFile = targetFiles.next();

     // Get the new content as a Blob
    var newContentBlob = Utilities.newBlob(attachment.getBytes())

    // Create a new revision by uploading the new content
    var updatedFile = Drive.Files.update({}, targetFile.getId(), newContentBlob);

    // Set the name to ensure it's the correct version
    updatedFile.setName(targetFileName);
  } 
}
```

Only one issue left to tackle though. I have created a shareable link to the file. After the upload completes and someone tries to access the file with the link, the page loads albeit with a Google error stating: "Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes." I can fix this by logging into the Google account hosting this file and opening it up directly by double clicking on it so that it opens in a new tab but thats quite inconvenient and defeats the purpose of the automated upload in the first place.