# Issues viewing a preview of a Google Sheets doc

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have an iOS app that I am currently developing. Within the app, I am trying to display a Google doc in a web view. So far, I have been successful in achieving this by hosting the file (currently a jpg) in Google drive, creating a shareable link to the file and defining the link in my application. The link I have been using so far is a preview link, formatted as such: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/InsertGoogleDriveFileIDHere/preview`

This has been very reliable over the past year but since I had to manually upload new versions of the file using the "Manage Versions" function, I sought to find a way to automate the process. I found that Google Scripts could help me automate this, which I have been able to implement somewhat successfully. My Google Script code will now check a folder on my email account for a new version of the document and then upload the new version of the document to Google Drive. The document is an excel document (I was previously taking a screenshot of this document and uploading that as a jpg). The new version of the excel file is successfully uploaded as a new managed version of the existing file I have on Google Drive, so I dont have to change the link in the app every time. The only thing I had to change is the preview link since its now an excel sheet: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/InsertGoogleDriveFileIDHere/preview`

Here's the issue. After the new version of the file is uploaded and I go to open it, the page loads but instead of a preview there is a Google error that reads: `"Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes."` It doesn't matter if I try and open the link in the webview in my app, on my phone or any browser on my desktop. However, if I log into Google Drive on my desktop and open the file manually by double clicking on it to open in a new tab, the shared link begins to work without any issues.

I've tried searching for an answer but I keep coming up short. For anyone interested, here is a link to my Google Script code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78017965/22499999

I'm not sure if its an issue with the code itself, a setting I am missing or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated!